# Load react-admin resources by default and use in form

Tags: react-admin

**Context:**

I have a Venue resource as well as a Room resource. The Venue has Rooms.

In my CreateRoom form I want to make some fields optional or required based on the Venue's type.

**Question:**

- How can I get the venue's type into my CreateRoom to dynamically render my form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to use a  to get the value from a form element and Query (or a hook, if you like those) to then get the data related to it.

- https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#linking-two-inputs
- https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html